# Changing Validation Text at change password page in magento2

Tags: validation, password, edit, change-password, text

I want to change or edit the validation text(Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than 8 symbols. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.) at change password page also shown here in picture,
 may somebody please suggest which file should i touch or edit for doing this. 
I tried edit a file - 
/var/www/html/development_m241/m241/vendor/magento/module-security/Test/Mftf/Test/NewCustomerPasswordLengthTest.xml  (at line no. 41)
 but not sure if it is only file i should play with or any other way to do this. 
[![screenshot error][1]][1]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which actually worked in my case is 
I edited the code in this file 
root_of_your_magento_folder/lib/web/mage/validation.js 
Near line number 687

```
    'validate-customer-password': [      //line number 677
               function (v, elm) {
    .
    .(gap of 10 lines)
    .//line number 687 i commented the old and added the new line
    //validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__('Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.').replace('%1', passwordMinLength); //eslint-disable-line max-len <br>
    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__('Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols.').replace('%1', passwordMinLength); //eslint-disable-line max-len
```

Please feel free to ask me and know any more details